# How to find the mean and variance of this stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

$
I_t = \int_0^t e^{i W_s} dWs
$
where $W_s$ is the standard brownian motion and $i$ is the complex number. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Evaluate sounds too vague for me. You want a close formula or you want to simulate it... it would be nice to have more details.

Comment: What do you mean "it looks like"? What does the "It" refer to?

Comment: @Pandaaaaaaa you changed the question pretty drastically, how can you be sure this is what he wanted originally?

Comment: @SRKX I have seen the same problem somewhere. It asks for variance and mean.

Answer (score 1):

This process is martingale and we have

$$
E[I_t|t=0]=0
$$

To find the variance, let's write it into differential form
$$
dI_t =e^{iW_t}dW_t
$$
Apply Ito's isometry
$$
Var(I_t)=\int_0^tE[e^{2iW_s}]ds
$$
Apply MGF of normal
$$
Var(I_t)=\int_0^te^{\frac{1}{2}(2i)^2s}ds=\int_0^te^{-2s}ds=\frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2}
$$
Please  let me know if anything is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

The expectation of an Itô integral (and a Wiener integral) is always zero.

Comment: This does not answer the question and rather has the quality of a comment.